# How to monitor a spring-boot application via JMX?

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-boot, visualvm

I'm trying to set up a JMX monitoring for a comand line app build with `spring-boot`.

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-actuator I just have to add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now I start my app, open VisualVM and I already see my application PID.
But how can I now access the metrics like `/health` etc that are mentioned on the `actuator` page? As this is a comand line app, I don't have any HTTP path that I can execute.

How can I see those metrics via JXM?

Comment: Have you actually tried connecting to that PID...

Comment: yes of course I'm connected and also see the heap etc, but not the jmx beans of spring

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to access JMX beans with JVisualVM, you need to install the VisualVM-MBeans plugin (go to Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins). You can also use JConsole, which can access JMX beans by default.

Answer (score -1):

Follow up: you have to set up a JMX port at startup; something like this:

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8000 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

FRom VisualVM then, Add JMX Connexion (in this example localhost:8000) in order to reach the app. Also see Launcher parameters into an IDE like Eclipse.
NB: credentials can be set as well, see JMX manual for options.