# How to detect connections leaks /open connections in a Java application without using DB tools

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, connection-pooling

Problem:
I got report from DB team reporting lot of connections open and it is not closed.

Expectation:
How to identify easily connection leaks or open connection in a java/spring boot application?

Comment: please use jconsole and monitor threads

Comment: Have the firewall team check if this is a case of the intermediate firewall closing "stale" connections. Both the DB and the Java Web-app won't know this  happened. Solution would be to set tcp keep-alive.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually leaking connections, and not just have a connection pool to is too large? Connection pools keep connections open for reuse, which might give the impression to your DBA team that you are not closing connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope Jconsole or JMX will help

Reference link

[JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763410/how-to-monitor-a-spring-boot-application-via-jmx)

[Jconsole](https://blog.e-zest.com/monitoring-database-connection-pooling/)